# How to add addional IP addresses to an interface through batch file

Tags: windows, networking, ip, batch-file

I have assigned a IP address to my LAN interface through

```
netsh int ip set address "LAN" static 192.168.0.99 255.255.255.0 192.168.0.1
```

Now I want to add `192.168.4.20` with gateway `192.168.4.1` to the same interface **without overwriting the existing IP address**.

How can I do this through a batch file?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this URL](http://www.nthelp.com/w2k3/to_add_a_bunch_of_ip_addresses.htm) it is possible to do this via:

```
netsh in ip add address "Local Area Connection" 172.16.1.2 255.255.0.0
```

(netsh int ip **add** rather than netsh int ip **set**).

Answer (score 0):

You can add second ip address like below:

```
netsh interface ip set address "Wi-Fi" static 10.0.0.5 255.255.255.0 10.0.0.1 
netsh interface ip add address "Wi-Fi" 192.168.1.51 255.255.255.0 
netsh interface ip set dns "Wi-Fi" static 8.8.8.8
netsh interface ip add dns "Wi-Fi" 8.8.4.4
```